# Simple calculator using command line with C++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, calculator

I'm writing a project that we do simple calculator from command line. The users input in this format **programname firstNumber operator secondNumber**. Here what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <number> <operator> <number>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        double firstNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
        char theOperator = argv[2][0];
        double secondNumber = atoi(argv[3]);
        switch (theOperator)
        {
        case'+':
        {
                   cout << "The answer is " << firstNumber + secondNumber << endl;
                   break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
                    cout << "The answer is " << firstNumber - secondNumber << endl;
                    break;
        }
        case '*':
        {
                    cout << "The answer is " << firstNumber * secondNumber << endl;
                    break;
        }
        case '/':
        {
                    if (secondNumber == 0)
                    {
                        cout << "Can not devide by a ZERO" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "The answer is " << firstNumber / secondNumber << endl;
                        break;
                    }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with a problem that my project does the calculation wrong for decimal numbers. For example, if I do 2.5 + 1.25, the result is 3. Can anyone please help me? I'm new to C++

Comment: `atoi(argv[1])` converts the number into an integer.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct, but I'm going to pitch using [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) instead of atof in the name of Eris and because it's easier to check the input for correctness.

```
char * endp;
double firstNumber;
if (argv[1][0] != '\0')
{ // input string is not empty 
    firstNumber = strtod (argv[1], &endp);
    if (*endp != '\0')
    { // number didn't end at the end of the string. String not a number.
        cout << "First number was not a number, dude." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Can't do much without a number, dude." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With atof, the program can be called with "I'm the very model of a modern major-general" and produce results. Bad results, but results all the same.

Oh, and warning on calling `exit` in C++. The program stops dead right there, and no destructors are called. No harm here, but not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 3):

In the lines

```
double firstNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
```

and

```
double secondNumber = atoi(argv[3]);
```

`atoi` converts the parameter into an `int` (hence truncating after the decimal point). You need to convert it into a `double`. You should instead use [`std::atof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof), or,  if using C++11, may also use `std::stod(argv[1]);`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem:

```
double firstNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
char theOperator = argv[2][0];
double secondNumber = atoi(argv[3]);
```

[`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) converts a string to an `int`, so `2.5` will be converted to `2` and `1.25` will be converted to 1, that's why you get the result `2 + 1 = 3`. Use [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you transform the string in numbers: you are using `atoi` which like its name suggests transforms the input in a integer.

The solution is to simply replace this by `atof` which will read correctly floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @meneldal suggestion, you can also use stringstream in C++ to convert from string to number

```
double value;
stringstream(someString) >> value;
```