# Simple calculator with numeric values only C++

Tags: c++, regex, command-line, calculator

I'm writing a simple calculator that calculate only numeric values. I need to use command line argument for my project. The argument needs to be in this format: 
**programname firstNumber operation secondNumber**. My project works fine except for non-numeric value. For example, If I do abc - def, the project doesn't reject it, it displays an answer equal 0. I tried to do regular expression for my project, but it doesn't work. Here what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
double numValidation();
double result;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <number> <operator> <number>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        double firstNumber = atof(argv[1]); 
        char theOperator = argv[2][0];
        double secondNumber = atof(argv[3]);
        switch (theOperator)
        {
        case'+':
            {
                result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                cout << "The answer is " << result << endl;
                break;
            }
        case '-':
            {
                result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                cout << "The answer is " << result << endl;
                break;
            }
        case '*':
            {
                result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                cout << "The answer is " << result << endl;
                break;
            }
        case '/':
            {
                if (secondNumber == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Can not devide by a ZERO" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                    cout << "The answer is " << result << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
double numValidation(string input)
{
    regex value("((\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+)(\\.(([[:digit:]]+)?))?");
    if (regex_match(input, value) && input.length() <= 10)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Input must be numeric value: ";
    }

}
```

I'm new to C++ and my instructor never shows us regular expression. Not sure regular expression is a good way to do calculation with only numeric values. Can anyone help me fix my regular expression or suggest me another way to solve my problem please? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex here? Just check that each character in the input is in the range of valid characters.

Comment: " doesn't work"? Did you get an error? Or an output which is not the expected one? Be more specific.

Comment: @m.s. If I use a regex, the answer always become 0 for non-numeric values.

Comment: @shuttle87 Can you be more specific please? It would be nice if you can explain it on codes, I'm new to C++. Sorry

Comment: One of the answers from last time you asked a question for this project covers this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30090381/3807729

Comment: Well, that explains the sudden flurry of interest in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using atof to parse your numbers, which is harder to check for errors in.

You may wish to use errno + strtod, which allows for error handling.  Here is a complete working example program.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* *argv)
{
    char *err;
    double d = strtod( argv[1], &err );
    if(errno || *err != 0) {
        // errno checks out of range, err checks other errors like non-numeric
        printf("That's no double!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Value is %f", d );

    return 0;
}
```